# Generate select list options in javascript after recevinig JSON data from Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list in Controller (MVC)

```
public CompanyController() {
         _company = new List<CompanyModel>{
            new CompanyModel{Name="A 1", Email="a1@company.com", Group="Group1"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="A 2", Email="a2@company.com", Group="Group2"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="A 3", Email="a3@company.com", Group="Group3"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="B 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group1"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="C 1", Email="c1@company.com", Group="Group2"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="D 1", Email="d1@company.com", Group="Group4"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="E 1", Email="e1@company.com", Group="Group5"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="E 2", Email="e2@company.com", Group="Group6"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="F 1", Email="f1@company.com", Group="Group6"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="G 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group5"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="H 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group6"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="I 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group3"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="J 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group7"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="K 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group6"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="L 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group1"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="M 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group2"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="N 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group2"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="O 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group4"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="P 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group5"},            
            new CompanyModel{Name="R 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group5"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="S 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group8"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="T 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group8"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="U 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group1"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="V 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group2"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="X 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group4"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="Y 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group3"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="Z 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group3"},
            new CompanyModel{Name="W 1", Email="b1@company.com", Group="Group6"},
         };
      }
```

which I sent via JSON to JQuery as:

```
objectCompany = null;
data = "";

$.ajax({
         url: '/Company/List',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         success: function (msg) {
            data = msg;
         },
         complete: function () {
            objectCompany = data;
         }
      });
```

I want to append to my `select` tag `<select name="filters" id="filters"></select>` all options which has `Group` values without repeating the similar values.

**UPDATE**

```
if (objectCompany != null) {
     $("#filters").empty();
     $("#filters").html("<option value='all' selected='selected'>All groups</option>");
     var arrayUnique = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < objectCompany .length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < objectCompany .length; j++) {
           if (objectCompany [i].Group === objectCompany [j].Group) {
              j = ++i;
           }
        }
        arrayUnique.push(objectCompany [i].Group);
     }

     arrayUnique = arrayUnique.sort();

     $.each(arrayUnique, function (k, v) {
        $("#filters").append("<option value='" + v + "'>" + v + "</option>");
     });
      }
```

Update: Now it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why struggling with javascript? Why don't you use a view model? Why don't you prepare the data from your controller action so that all that the view has to do is display it? What's the purpose of wasting your bandwidth with some repeated groups in the JSON?

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    var model = _company.Select(x => x.Group).Distinct();
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now it's simple:

```
var filters = $('#filters');
filters.empty();
filters.append(
    $('<option/>', {
        value: 'all',
        selected: 'selected',
        text: 'All groups'
    })
);
$.each(objectCompany, function (index, group) {
    filters.append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: group,
            text: group
        })
    );
});
```

---

UPDATE:

If you want to do this filtering on the client side you could define a function which will get the distinct elements:

```
$.extend({
    distinct : function(arr, selector) {
       var result = [];
       $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
           var item = selector(value);
           if ($.inArray(item, result) == -1) {
               result.push(item);
           }
       });
       return result;
    }
});
```

and then:

```
var filters = $('#filters');
filters.empty();
filters.append(
    $('<option/>', {
        value: 'all',
        selected: 'selected',
        text: 'All groups'
    })
);
var groups = $.distinct(objectCompany, function(item) { return item.Group; });

$.each(groups, function (index, group) {
    filters.append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: group,
            text: group
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Becuase `objectCompany` will be re-used in other functions in JS and that's why I sent all data. I want to manipulate data only in JS I want to avoid to send data to server and get back the response. This object will be huge, I wrote here a part of it.

Comment: @MichaelSwan, well then write another controller action. Specifically designed for this AJAX call. I have also updated my answer to illustrate an example of selecting distinct elements on the client although I wouldn't recommend such approach.

Comment: see my updated code (last code written in JS)..Now it works :) Without calling and/or create another controller

Comment: the mod can close this question